# Can a python3.x function be defined in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

Checking an intro quiz I came across this q/a with no explanations:

Question 20 of 20

True or false, a function can be defined inside a function

True
 False

I chose True because you can define a nested function in a function, but the quiz marked it wrong.
Which is correct and why?
tx

Comment: Whoever wrote or scored the quiz is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering more for future readers rather than the OP, who chose the correct answer.)

You can absolutely define a function inside a function:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   def bar(y):
...       return x + y
...   return bar
...
>>> foo(3)(5)
8
```

The quiz is incorrect.